# Using Expect after SSH

Tags: bash, expect

I'm trying to install a pkg file on remote machines. Facing issue while using expect inside ssh. unable to pass the password  while using actual password or variable $pass

```
#!/bin/bash
agentpath="/Users/vigneshganapathy/Downloads/FS-Agent"
pass="xxx"
expect -c "spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no shyamkarthikv@192.168.57.33
      expect \"*?assword:\" {send \"$pass\r\"; exp_continue}
      spawn sudo installer -pkg \"/tmp/FS-Agent/FS-Agent.pkg\" -target \"/\"
      expect \"*?assword:\" {send \"xxx/r\"; exp_continue}"
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using `sshpass`, which is built for this purpose? Then it's only the `sudo installer` that's prompting -- and if you control `/etc/sudoers`, then you could configure even that to not request a password in the first place. (Moreover, an `/etc/sudoers` configured with interactive use in mind would disable the default check for a TTY, so you could just pass the command to run directly on the ssh command line without needing `ssh -t` or similar).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look like a correct expect-script to me. In general, it is a good idea to use an expect script instead of trying to put it all in an argument.

```
spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no shyamkarthikv@192.168.57.33
expect \"*?assword:\" 
{send \"$pass\r\"; exp_continue}
spawn sudo installer -pkg \"/tmp/FS-Agent/FS-Agent.pkg\" -target \"/\"
expect \"*?assword:\" 
{send \"xxx/r\"; exp_continue}"
```

So what this does is

- start an ssh-session on 192.168.57.33
- start `sudo installer` on the local machine

That is almost certainly not what you want. What I think that you want is:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

eval spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no shyamkarthikv@192.168.57.33
expect "ord:"
send "$env(PASSWORD)\r";
expect "~"
send "sudo installer -pkg /tmp/FS-Agent/FS-Agent.pkg -target /\r"
expect "ord:"
send "$env(PASSWORD)\r";
```

make sure you export the variable `PASSWORD` in your calling shell.

Comment: Pulling a password off argv is an unfortunate decision from a security perspective -- a given platform is much less likely to protect argv against snooping by other users than to protect the set of environment variables.

Comment: You are right, of course. Corrected it.

Comment: I'm curious, by the way -- what's the purpose of the `eval`? (I'm not nearly as handy with expect or TCL in general as I am with bash, so this is an entirely genuine question).

Comment: Here, it is quite useless I must admit. It is more a habit than having any real value. The function of eval is roughly the same as in `bash`. Most of the time, it is used when you want to build-up script parts and then execute them.

Answer (score 1):

here-documents are a good way to embed code from another language into a shell script: The heredoc word is quoted (`expect <<'END_EXPECT'`) which single-quotes the whole document. This allows you to not have to escape everything.

I use the environment to pass variables from shell to expect

I am assuming that you want to execute the "installer" command on the remote host, in which case, you want to `send` it not `spawn` it.

```
#!/bin/bash
agentpath="/Users/vigneshganapathy/Downloads/FS-Agent"
export pass="xxx"

expect <<'END_EXPECT'
    spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no shyamkarthikv@192.168.57.33
    expect { 
        "*?assword:" {
            send "$env(pass)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        somePatternThatMatchesYourPrompt
    }
    set timeout -1  ;# in case it takes a long time to complete
    send "sudo installer -pkg /tmp/FS-Agent/FS-Agent.pkg -target / \r"
    expect { 
        "*?assword:" {
            send "$env(pass)\r"
            exp_continue
        }
        somePatternThatMatchesYourPrompt
    }
    set timeout 2
    send "exit\r"
    expect eof
END_EXPECT
```